# Transform string date to Date object in JS

Tags: javascript, datetime

My input is get via an API, and I have this array with the following date format as strings:"*2022-06-29T15:30:00+00:00*", "*2022-07-01T09:00:00+00:00*", "*2022-07-05T16:00:00+00:00*".

I want to transform those date in another format (ex for the first one: 29.06.2022 (DD.MM.YYYY)).

Also, I want to compare dates to sort the array. How can I do this? Do I need to convert it into a Date object? (vanilla JS, no frameworks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider doing it like this:

```
const str = "2022-06-29T15:30:00+00:00";

const date = new Date(str);

console.log(date); // ️ Wed Jun 29 2022 22:30:00
```

As for sorting array based on dates, you can take a look at [How to sort an object array by date property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property).

Comment: @RobG You're right. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can first sort the dates using sort method

```
dateArr.sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b))
```

and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array

```js
const dateArr = [
    '2022-06-29T15:30:00+00:00',
    '2022-07-01T09:00:00+00:00',
    '2022-07-05T16:00:00+00:00',
];

const result = dateArr
    .sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b))
    .map((str) => str.split('T')[0].split('-').reverse().join('-'));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateStr = "2022-06-29T15:30:00+00:00";
let getDate = dateStr.split('T')[0];
const date = new Date(getDate);
```